# DBT: How can I pass an macros into model config to run this macro in materialization which is used by model?

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I'm trying to pass my dbt macro into model config like that:

```
{{ config(
custom_macro=my_macro
)
}}
```

my_macro is defined in /macros/my_macro.sql

Then I'm trying to run this macro in custom materialization like that:

```
{% if config.get("custom_macro", None) %}
        {% do my_macro('foo') %}
{% endif %}
```

But I get an error at compilation stage:
*TypeError: can not serialize 'MacroGenerator' object*

Okay, then I tried to pass macro name in string and tried to run it using adapter.dispatch or ref() and all methods thath I had googled. But no success.

Can anyone give me an advise how can I pass macro object in a right way or how can I dynamically run macro by macroname?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pass a macro as a parameter jinja dbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73363627/pass-a-macro-as-a-parameter-jinja-dbt)

Comment: @AdamKipnis no it doesn't, cause here is example how to set variable containing macros object and run this macros inside this model. My issue is run macro outside model but inside materialization that this model is using.